# With what intention should you immerse in the Mikvah?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, kavana-concentration, kavana-intent

I've just been reading Maimonides and he says in the Mishneh Torah (Immersion Pools chapter 11)

> Therefore the sages have said, if a man immerses himself, but without
>   special intention, it as though he has not immersed himself at all.

So I'm wondering what special intention should one have?

Comment: Did you see the rest of the section there? https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Immersion_Pools.11.12?lang=bi

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yossi and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

Actually The Rambam explains [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Other_Sources_of_Defilement.13.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that the intention that one must have is to purify for a specific level of sanctity i.e. for *Maaser Sheini* (second tithe of produce eaten in Jerusalem), *teruma* (Cohens portion of produce), for *Kodshim* (offerings in the Beth Hamikdash) or for sprinkling the *Mei Chatas* (solution of red cow ashes).

But for the Immersion of a Niddah or Baal keri for sake of eating regular *Chullin* (non-sanctified food) one does not need intention.

Comment: Unfortunately this misunderstands the question. This is not the kind of intent being discussed.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I was reading a paraphrased passage from "The Maimonides Reader." Have a great day!